# Flask CLI command not in __init__.py file

Tags: python, flask, flask-cli

I'm trying to add `commands` to my Flask app.

This is my `__init__.py` file:

```
import os

from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
from flask_mongoengine import MongoEngine

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)
app.config.from_object(os.environ['APP_SETTINGS'])

db = MongoEngine(app)

import slots_tracker_server.views  # noqa
```

If I add to it:

```
@app.cli.command()
def test_run():
    print('here')
```

I can run `flask test_run` with no problems, but if I try to move the code to another file, for example: `commands.py`, I get the error `Error: No such command "test_run".` when trying to run the command.

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `click` (the library behind Flask commands) to register your commands:

```
# commands.py
import click

@click.command()
def test_run():
    print('here')
```

In your `__init__.py` import and register the commands:

```
# __init__.py
from yourapp import commands

from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

app.cli.add_command(commands.test_run)
```

Take a look at the [official docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/cli/#application-context)

Comment: I was sure that I tried this, but now it works, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In you `commands.py` you can add register function like that:

```
def register(app):

    @app.cli.command(name='test_run', help="test_run command")
    def register_test_run():
        test_run()

    # other commands to register
```

And then in your `__init__.py` import this register function

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from commands import register
register(app)
```

Notice, that you should import `register` after you've initialized your `app`.